# Java Binding bean to String empty property

Tags: java, swing, binding, javabeans

I am trying to bind the visibility of a `JLabel` to whether the text of a `JTextField` is empty or not.

I want to do this because I want to hide the `JLabel` with a red asterisk, which denotes that filling in a text field is compulsory, so it should hide when it is filled in.

The following does however not work (with ${text.isEmpty}):

```
binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(
          org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, 
            estimatedCostTextField, 
            org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${text.isEmpty}"), 
            estimatedCostAsterisk, 
            org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("visible"));

bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You should use `${empty text}`

So the code becomes:

```
binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(
            org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, 
            estimatedCostTextField, 
            org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${empty text}"), 
            estimatedCostAsterisk, 
            org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("visible"));

bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
```